# Avoid executing system command with Ruby secure open

Tags: ruby, command, system

In terminal, typing:

```
> irb
> require('open-uri')
> open("| curl http://www.haosou.com").read
```

can execute a system command. How can I avoid this?

[image: ruby open curl]

Comment: @GaganGami  I mean how to avoid executing a system command `open("| curl http://www.haosou.com").read`, how to  avoid `open` execute          `curl`

Comment: Isn't it okay for you to just remove the `| curl` part ? I mean calling it with just `open("http://www.haosou.com").read` will give you the result you want, right ?

Comment: @malei0311 please accept the answer if your problem was solved.

Comment: @Pierre-JeanBergeron your answer can't solve my problem, if someone pass me a parameter like `| curl http://www.haosou.com`, it can execute a system command, it's not secure

Comment: Ok I understand your question better. I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Executing this kind of command is a serious security issue.

You can use a regex to validate the format:

```
/^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix
```

The validation can be done in a model:

```
validates_format_of :url, :with => /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix
```

Or elsewhere:

```
if url =~ /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix
    require('open-uri')
    open(url).read
end
```